# Run jobs when there are changes in a particular folder on feature branch, else run the job on master irrespective of the change

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-branch, jobs

I wanted to check if I can run a job having condition only/changes: when there is a change in a particular folder on the feature branch and the same job should always run on the master branch irrespective of the change condition is been met.

```
thevers:
  stage: stage_1
  tags:
   - dind
   - stable
  before_script:
    - *install_grails_debian
  script:
    - ./grailsw clean-all --non-interactive
    - ./grailsw refresh-dependencies --non-interactive
    - ./grailsw maven-install
  only:
    changes:
      - thevers/**/*
  artifacts:
    name: "$CI_PROJECT_NAME-$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
    paths:
     - .m2/
    expire_in: 5 days
    when: always
  allow_failure: true
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment the only way to do what you're requesting is to duplicate the job, with one job specifying `only:changes` section as you have now and another with:

```
only:
  - master
```

A future release will introduce more flexible rules for CI jobs which will make this much easier for you. Keep an eye on [GitLab CE issue 60085](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/60085).

Comment: Glad it was helpful! If it was the right answer to your question, please accept the answer.